# jquery swipe to navigate example with elements won't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm redesigning a website to fit on mobile devices. I want to add swipe left and right to navigate and found a way with this jquery example:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/swipe-page/

When I added this to my site it worked perfectly. That is, until I put some elements within the div with data-role='page'.

I've tried this with the example JQuery gave and I'm having the same problem. In this example (www.jouwjoure.nl/test/newyork.html), I put in a div in the  and tried to swipe.

The swipe works outside the div I put in, but when I swipe within the div I put in, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the comments in the demo source code:

```
// Navigate to the next page on swipeleft
$( document ).on( "swipeleft", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
    // Get the filename of the next page. We stored that in the data-next
    // attribute in the original markup.
    var next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" );

    // Check if there is a next page and
    // swipes may also happen when the user highlights text, so ignore those.
    // We're only interested in swipes on the page.
    if ( next && ( event.target === $( this )[ 0 ] ) ) {
        navnext( next );
    }
});
```

You may change the code, to get the swipe done if you add other elements. Just an example:

```
// Navigate to the next page on swipeleft
$( document ).on( "swipeleft", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
    var currPage = $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("getActivePage");
    var next = $(currPage).jqmData( "next" );
    if ( next ) {
        navnext( next );
    }
});
```

Additional hint (depending from your requirements):

Moreover, to avoid additional nasty side effects, you may also set `unselectable` and `undraggable` on your added overlay elements. Try it out.